# Delay until await returns a True

Tags: vb.net, shopify

Delay until await returns a True

I have looked at many examples of Delaying a for while loop until a result is gained; but can't come up with a solution that will not hang the system forever if the boolean variable is not attained.

I have used Thread.Sleep but it stops the await thread from returning a result. I need someone to assist me in finding a solution where the system will wait for the "LoadedShopifyProduct" to be true then continue with the "Button1.click".

*** You will see that the try variable stops once 40 is reached so I really don't  know whether the products have been loaded. Is there a better option then Thread.Sleep?

```
Private Sub TEST
            Show()
            TopMost = True
            Dim HasInternet As Boolean = crm.HaveInternetConnection() :'check if there is internet
            If HasInternet = False Then
                Me.Close()
                Exit sub
            End If
            Form1.LoadShopifyProducts():'calls the Async routine
            Dim trys As Short = 0
            While LoadedShopifyProducts = False And HasInternet = True And trys < 40
                Form1.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Tries : " & trys & " -> Shopify Products Not loaded ! Please wait a few seconds"
                Application.DoEvents()
                Thread.Sleep(2000)
                trys = trys + 1
            End While
            Button1.PerformClick() : 'do next 
End Sub
Public Async Sub LoadShopifyProducts()        
        Dim HasInternet As Boolean = crm.HaveInternetConnection()
        If HasInternet = True Then
            TimesShopifyLoad = TimesShopifyLoad + 1
            
            Dim BaseURL = Para(Val(TermNumber), 580)
            Dim Key = Para(Val(TermNumber), 581)

            Dim shopifyClient As New ShopifyApi(BaseURL, Key)
            shopifyClient.Initialise()

            'retrieve all Products from Shopify API
            allShopifyProducts = Await shopifyClient.GetAllProducts()
            'also collate a master list of all Variants from the list of Products returned above to allow searching by SKU which only appears on the variant
            allShopifyVariants = Await shopifyClient.GetAllVariants(allShopifyProducts)
           
           LoadedShopifyProducts = True :' after await set ---> to true ! ! 
            CountShopify = allShopifyVariants.Count
        
            ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "( Shopify : " & allShopifyVariants.Count & " ) Times:" & Str(TimesShopifyLoad)
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Couple thoughts on a quick eyeballing.  1)  Button1.PerformClick(),  don't do this.  Create a new method that replicates the current button click event, then call it from  the button click and this method.  2) Application.DoEvents() I have yet in 20yrs experience seen a valid need to call this directly other than hack around other hacks.  Gut feeling if this is required for your app to function, there is a much bigger up stream issue.  And wouldn't make much more sense to simply return a boolean from LoadShopifyProducts() to indicate success or failure?

Comment: @Hursey. Re `DoEvents`. In WordBasic for Winword 1 and 2 (and the others ExcelBasic) some dialogs did not have programmatic access. You would `sendkeys` and then call `DoEvents` to allow processing of the key. A current use in VBA is for asynchronous WMI events.

Comment: @Lundt.  WordBasic, ExcelBasic and VBA are complete different product so see no relevance to this.  Application.DoEvents() hasn't been a thing since the days of VB6 and even then it's usage should of been limited

Comment: @Hursey I've explained why it exists. `InputBox` only exists because QuickBasic for Dos had the `Input` command. Basic for 16 bit cooperatively multitasked Windows needed `DoEvents` to completely automate Word. All programs can call `Yield` in the 16 bit API. **Anything that was in a previous version is in current versions to make porting code easy**. And as I've explained you need `DoEvents` to h.andle asynchronous WMI events in a non form VB6/VBA (and sleep in VBScript).

Comment: @Lundt, not debating why DoEvents exists.  Questioning the usage in this context.  This question is clearly tagged as vb.net so cannot understand what relevance Quickbasice or any variations of VBA to this question.

Comment: @Hursey You said this *have yet in 20yrs experience seen a valid need to call this directly other than hack around other hacks.*.

Comment: The statement "delay until Await returns true" doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.  If `LoadShopifyProducts` were written correctly as a `Function` returning `Task(Of Boolean`), as soon as you `Await` it, that's exactly what will happen.

Comment: Note that `Async` and `Await` are "viral"; it's basically never the right thing to do to call an async routine directly, it should *always* be awaited (so as soon as one thing in a call chain is async, all should be).  The starting point will typically be an async event handler (which is, incidentally, the only thing that should ever be an `Async Sub`).

Comment: @Craig - How would you write LoadShopifyProduct as a function . . . This goes over my head - please give an example !

Comment: I would recommend to start by reading more on how `Async` and `Await` work.  Your questions suggest that you don't understand it very well (and that's not a value judgment, it's hard to wrap your head around it).  If you want to do it right, you need to understand what it does and how it works.  Eric Lippert has some blog articles that relate async and await to continuation passing, which might help, and Stephen Cleary has a bunch of articles that I found to be very helpful.

Comment: In this case specifically, if you just change the signature exactly how I showed---and you may lose the ability to use the implicit result variable when you do this, though I haven't tested it---it will work as intended as long as you `Await` the result in `Test`.

Comment: Never ever ever use `DoEvents()`. It's evil incarnate. It will cause you grief.

Comment: Don't use the default form instance (i.e. don't use `Form1.XXX`). Instead always instantiate a new instance.

Comment: Always use `Option Strict On` when writing VB - it will make you work a little harder, but your code will be far more robust!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would do the basic version of what you want:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
    If crm.HaveInternetConnection() Then
        Dim variants = Await GetShopifyProducts(Para(Val(TermNumber), 580), Para(Val(TermNumber), 581))
        ' Do something with the variants
    End If
End Sub

Private Async Function GetShopifyProducts(BaseURL As String, Key As String) As Task(Of ShopifyVariant())
    Dim shopifyClient As New ShopifyApi(BaseURL, Key)
    shopifyClient.Initialise()
    Dim products = Await shopifyClient.GetAllProducts()
    Dim variants = Await shopifyClient.GetAllVariants(products)
    Return variants
End Function
```

If you needed to repeat the call every 2 seconds until a condition is met, then it looks like this:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
    Me.Timer1.Interval = 2000
    Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
    If crm.HaveInternetConnection() Then
        Dim variants = Await GetShopifyProducts(Para(Val(TermNumber), 580), Para(Val(TermNumber), 581))
        ' Do something with the variants
        If TurnOffTimerCondition Then
            Me.Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Async Function GetShopifyProducts(BaseURL As String, Key As String) As Task(Of ShopifyVariant())
    Dim shopifyClient As New ShopifyApi(BaseURL, Key)
    shopifyClient.Initialise()
    Dim products = Await shopifyClient.GetAllProducts()
    Dim variants = Await shopifyClient.GetAllVariants(products)
    Return variants
End Function
```

---

Update with example timeout:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
    If Me.Timer1.Enabled = False Then
        Me.Timer1.Interval = 2000
        Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    End If
End Sub

Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
    If crm.HaveInternetConnection() Then
        Dim variants = Await GetShopifyProducts(Para(Val(TermNumber), 580), Para(Val(TermNumber), 581))
        ' Do something with the variants
        If sw.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) Then
            Me.Timer1.Enabled = False
            MessageBox.Show("not met in 60 seconds")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem I am facing is two things :- 1) Button1 is in a Private Sub and does many other things I can't make it Async 2) There will be an endless loop if the condition of all items loaded is not met;  I need a mechanism where if an X number of seconds pass it must stop processing and not perform the button1 click (show a message stating not met in X seconds)

Comment: @BASitBulbulia - (1) There is no problem with `Button1_Click` being `Private`- that works just fine. (2) You're the programmer so you can set any condition to stop the "loop". In this case you just need to determine when to call `Me.Timer1.Enabled = False`.

Comment: @BASitBulbulia - I've added a more detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a background worker and call you function from background workers do work at an event. by using a background worker you can prevent the system from hangup and also can show some progress bars before calling the background worker and hiding on completion.